# Array of Buttons - One Event Handler - Figuring Out Which Button Was Clicked

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I have no easy way to explain this but I have 100 buttons, written up to be in an array of buttons with this here line of code:

```
static array <Button^, 2>^ button = gcnew array <Button^, 2> (10,10);
```

And each one is initialized following this suit:

```
button[4,0] = button40;
```

I also have one event handler for all of these buttons. What I need to know is what is a way I can determine which button has been clicked for example if you click the button in the third row and the fourth column, it should know that button named button23 (saved in array as button[2,3]) has been pressed.

Also another thing, this is C++/CLI and I'm aware of how weird this code is.

Comment: Wow, that's a hell lot of buttons and event handlers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler you have the `sender` of the event:

```
void button_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    // This is the name of the button
    String^ buttonName = safe_cast<Button^>(sender)->Name;
}
```

If you need item's indices (row and column) you need to loop through array because `Array::IndexOf` doesn't support multidimensional arrays. Let's write (somewhere) a generic function like this:

```
static void Somewhere::IndexOf(Array^ matrix, Object^ element, int% row, int% column)
{
    row = column = -1;

    for (int i=matrix->GetLowerBound(0); i <= matrix->GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
    {
        for (int i=matrix->GetLowerBound(1); i <= matrix->GetUpperBound(1); ++i)
        {
            // Note reference comparison, this won't work with boxed value types
            if (Object::ReferenceEquals(matrix->GetValue(i, j), element)
            {
                row = i;
                column = j;

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So finally you may have this:

```
void button_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    // This is the name of the button
    String^ buttonName = safe_cast<Button^>(sender)->Name;

    // This is the "location" of the button
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    Somewhere::IndexOf(button, sender, row, column);
}
```